# Setting up a Name Servers for a website?

Tags: windows-server-2003, nameserver

I'm a total newbie to Server 2k3 here. I have a 2k3 server using a static IP(it's a game server which people use this IP to connect), which I connect using remote desktop. I've also registered a domain name for my website(example.com).

What I'm trying to do is when users enter example.com in browser they get my installed apache `localhost` on my server(so simple).

I could simply create a subdomain(using CPanel, I'm already using a webspace and host provider for this domain) like sub.example.com and set an IP(works fine) but I need the main domain name to be set.
Here in domain control panel(of example.com) I need two `Domain Name`s to enter in order to work. Something like ns1.example.com and ns2.example.com.

I haven't set up any Active Directory or DNS yet on my server cause I actually don't know which I need(maybe both).

What steps I need to take, making this to happen?
What information I need to ask my ISP(like pref and alter DNS IPs, default gateway,..)?
I've googled this but I'm not sure I'm reading the right stuff, Is there a useful article you can point me to(specific for my case)?

Sorry again for newbie question or if this exact question already exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you already have the 2 Nameservers that you are looking for provided by your domain name registrar, which are controlled via the cpanel Domains section. You are looking to create an "A Record" which points to your apache installation.

In cpanel this can be achieved if you have the "Simple DNS Zone Editor" option in the "Domains" section you can add an "A record" which should be filled out with your static IP address and your "example.com" domain.

The "Name" field should be specified with a suffixed dot to indicate that the address is absolute and not a sub-domain. eg;

Name: example.com.

see

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I should enter `example.com` in `Name` and ` my static IP` in `address` field, right?

Comment: yes, also I think you have to specify "Name"  as your domain with a suffixed dot like `example.com.` to indicate that the domain is absolute, rather than a sub-domain.

Answer (score 0):

First, realize that stumbling through this is almost certain to lead to a lot of headaches. It's about the only way to learn this stuff without getting someone to help you though.

Sounds like you've got DNS hosting going already. If that's the case you probably **do not** want to install MS DNS server. You definitely don't want to install Active Directory.

If you **do** want to run your own DNS server: Add the DNS Server role to Windows. Configure the DNS server for your domain(s). Configure a backup DNS service, don't forget to add your the backup DNS configuration to your server (they'll provide directions), free Backup DNS available (Google finds them quick), configure your registrar with the two+ DNS servers, and Bob's your uncle.

If you want people to be able to use `example.com` then you'll need a default A Record (usually it's call the `@` A Record). Only A and CNAME records mean anything to web browsers, all the rest of the record types mean absolutely squat.

In any case we don't know nearly enough about your specific setup to walk you through the process, and further it seems you have a lot to learn about these systems before you would want to run your own. Probably best off staying with hosted services.

Comment: Thank you for this. I don't need dns hosting anymore after this setup. I'm researching and learning about A and CNAME records right now :) Also this is not just a web browser thing. This is a RPG game server which people needs to enter IP(I want them to use domain name instead, this is actually the whole goal of this)

Comment: As a general rule of thumb, if the application doesn't specifically call out some DNS record type it's always A and CNAME records. Games of any kind fall into that category.

Comment: No problem then, the IP(or Domain) is the way that connection between client and server is established. It's all about send/receive through a port.